# Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
const Post = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const slug = router.query.postslug;
    const currentPost = PostData.find((post) => post.slug === slug);

    return (

        currentPost.content

    )
}

export default Post;
```

Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')

Below is the array of objects

```
const PostData = [
    {
        id:1,
        slug:...,
        content:...
    }
]
```

Comment: PostData, where exactly is that from, I think we need some more information/code.

Comment: Done. You can see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that content is **undefined** in context of currentPost.
Its undefined because PostData doesnt match the slug.

a quick guard should help the solution

```
{ currentPost &&  currentPost.content}
```

Comment: This is generating a syntax errors.

Comment: Can you paste the error? Propably your issue is that you return null in render.
Wrap this answer in a div or fragment and it should work allright

Comment: ./pages/blog/[postslug].js
Error: error: Expression expected
    
     |
2795 |         { currentPost && currentPost.content}
     |                       ^^

error: Expected ',', got '}'
    
     |
2795 |         { currentPost && currentPost.content}
     |                                             ^

Caused by:
    0: failed to process js file
    1: Syntax Error

Comment: Now working fine when enclosed your syntax in fragments

Comment: Perfect, if this helps you please mark this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend preparing for it not finding anything like this:

```
currentPost?.content
```

If you believe this shouldn't give an error ever, as you haven't said this, feel free to return with a comment/edit describing your problem a bit more.

Comment: Error: Post(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.